Multiple imageview' OnClickListener() android studio
i want to add multiple image view onClick to different page of Activity on android, but it doesn't work. The App can't run without error msg. The app Main Page is similar to mobile desktop. it include different image and user can click the image and change to different pages. So how can i change the code, app doesn't show an error, only show can't run app. Thank you.
package com.example.myapplication.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import com.example.myapplication.Activities.PhotoAndCamera.CameraActivity;
import com.example.myapplication.Activities.PhotoAndCamera.PhotoActivity;
import com.example.myapplication.Activities.StoreData.StoreActivity;
import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.Activities.Weather.WeatherActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageButton BtnProfile;
    ImageView BtnWeather, BtnCamera, BtnPhoto, BtnStore;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BtnWeather = findViewById(R.id.BtnWeather);
        BtnCamera = findViewById(R.id.BtnCamera);
        BtnPhoto = findViewById(R.id.BtnPhoto);
        BtnStore = findViewById(R.id.BtnStore);
        BtnProfile = findViewById(R.id.BtnProfile);

        BtnWeather.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnStore.setOnClickListener(this);
        BtnProfile.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()== R.id.BtnWeather) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WeatherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (v.getId()== R.id.BtnCamera) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (v.getId()== R.id.BtnPhoto) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhotoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (v.getId()== R.id.BtnStore) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StoreActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (v.getId()== R.id.BtnProfile) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EFF0FC"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/top_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="John Leung"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView13"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_account_circle_80" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_background"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/top_banner_background"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/BtnProfile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/video_call" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TxtProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Profile"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#6672FF"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/top_banner_background"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/notification" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Notification"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#6672FF"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/top_banner_background"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView14"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/voice_call" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView17"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Voice Call"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#6672FF"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Search For ..."
        android:textStyle="italic|bold"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_edittext"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextText2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/BtnWeather"
                        android:layout_width="38dp"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cloudy_sunny" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Weather"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/BtnMaps"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_2" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView24"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Maps"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_3" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView25"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Chats"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/BtnPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_insert_photo_24" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView26"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Photo"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/BtnStore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_5" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TxtStore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Store Data"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/BtnCamera"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="71dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView20"
                        android:layout_width="41dp"
                        android:layout_height="31dp"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_camera_alt_24" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView28"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Camera"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_7" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView29"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Settings"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/BtnAlarm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_background">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                        android:layout_width="37dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_alarm" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Alarm"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#2e3d6d"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


What is the error? What "doesn't work"?

cannot run the app.. when build app, it will shut down immediately

Share the error message and Layout codes for better understanding

android studio didn't show any error msg. but when i run the app. the app keep showing "The application keeps stopping"
